# Difficulty of generating a string "The (md5|sha1) hash of this string is (x)" that hashes to (x) vs. regular hash collision between files?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-1, md5, hardness-assumptions

I know that collisions in md5 and sha1 have been demonstrated in particular pairs of files (by incrementing some none viewable portion of a PDF, etc).

Would generating the above string be meaningfully more computationally difficult than generating such a collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it would be much more difficult to generate a *string* of the form `The (MD5|SHA-1) hash of this string is (x)` where `x` is (in hexadecimal or binary) the hash of that string, than it is to find collisions for MD5 or SHA-1. In fact, even though we can generate collisions for MD5 at low cost including for short messages (64-octet), I don't think that we could plug this one. Main issue is that the string `x` that we can change is much too small, and the rest too constrained.

However, we can easily construct a family of $2^{128}$ octet strings all with the same MD5 hash that are valid PDF documents and display any desired 128-bit value in hexadecimal, including one such document (that we can exhibit) displaying its own hash. That also works for Postscript, non-signed executables.. It would be feasible to do this for SHA-1, but that would cost about 128 times more work than what was used for one collision.

The trick is to start from a PDF document that displays a value depending on its content at 128 bits changing in 128 different local changes that each leave the hash invariant; each change involving altering 2 message blocks for SHA-1, or just 1 for MD5.

Update: That trick was pulled for a [GIF image!](https://shells.aachen.ccc.de/~spq/md5.gif)